# DivX Plugin IE8 Jquery Error

Tags: jquery, plugins, divx

I have found out that DivX Plugin crashes in IE8. The problem is discussed here too Hello,

http://drupal.org/node/1038058.

When you press to open a modal window (lightbox etc) the tagName is null and javascript crashes! DivX Plugin try to inject jquery code which replaces flash video to html5 video and this code creates this error.
Unfortunately haven't found a solution for this...

Have you something to sugggest? Maybe a way to either plugin to run programmatically?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the DivX plugin. Uninstall or disable it.

If that's not an option, use JavaScript to detect the presence of the plugin, and if found, alert the user that the page will not function properly with the DivX plugin. See the [JavaScript API docs](http://labs.divx.com/node/16582).